# Using Query datatype in C#

Tags: c#, axapta, ax

I have a piece of code which returns a Sales Order from AX. In that record im using the querySalesLine method but I'm not sure where I go from there to get all the lines attached to the order below is my code:

```
AxaptaRecord OrderRecord = (AxaptaRecord)ax.CallStaticClassMethod("OnlineOrder", "getSalesOrder", salesRef);

if(OrderRecord.Found)
{
     AxaptaObject Lines = (AxaptaObject)OrderRecord.Call("querySalesLine");
}
```

How would I then use this Lines object to retrieve all of the items attached to this order? I know that the querySalesLine returns a Query object but not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `QueryRun` object, then use that object to read the lines.

```
var qLines = (AxaptaObject)OrderRecord.Call("querySalesLine");
var qrLines = ax.CreateAxaptaObject("QueryRun", qLines);
```

To read the lines use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9678925/4509).

The [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb278121%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) is a static description of the query.

The [QueryRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa627671%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) uses the query to find the records.